# Autodiscover URL with default credentials in EWS

Tags: c++, exchangewebservices

Is it possible to use the AutoDiscoverURL() function to set the URL without providing an e-mail adress, that is, taking advantage of the e-mail associated with the Windows login?

Thank you

Comment: did you have any solution to this? I'm with the same problem. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I did not. You have to provide an adress.